# Transform JavaPairDStream to Tuple3 in Java

Tags: apache-spark

I am experimenting with the Spark job that streams data from **Kafka** and produces to **Cassandra**.

The sample I am working with takes a bunch of words in a given time interval and publishes the word count to **Cassandra**. I am also trying to also publish the timestamp along with the *word* and its *count*.

What I have so far is as follows:

```java
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkQuorum, groupId, topicMap);

JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
            .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
```

Now I am trying to append to these records the **timestamp**. What I have tried is something like this:

```java
Tuple3<String, Date, Integer> finalRecord =
            wordCounts.map(s -> new Tuple3<>(s._1(), new Date().getTime(), s._2()));
```

Which of course is shown as wrong in my IDE. I am completely new to working with Spark libraries and writing in this form (*I guess lambda based*) functions.

Can someone help me correct this error and achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching done on the web and studying some examples I was able to achieve what I wanted as follows.

In order to append the **timestamp** attribute to the existing *Tuple* with two values, I had to create a simple bean with which represents my **Cassandra** row.

```java
public static class WordCountRow implements Serializable {
        String word = "";
        long timestamp;
        Integer count = 0;
```

Then, I had map the *(word, count)* **Tuple2** objects in the *JavaPairDStream* structure to a *JavaDStream* structure that holds objects of the above **WordCountRow** class.

```java
JavaDStream<WordCountRow> wordCountRows = wordCounts.map((Function<Tuple2<String, Integer>, WordCountRow>)
                tuple -> new WordCountRow(tuple._1, new Date().getTime(), tuple._2));
```

Finally, I could call **foreachRDD** method on this structure *(which returns objects of **WordCountRow**)* which I can write to **Cassandra** one after the other.

```java
wordCountRows.foreachRDD((VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<WordCountRow>,Time>)(rdd,time)->{
            final SparkConf sc=rdd.context().getConf();
            final CassandraConnector cc=CassandraConnector.apply(sc);
            rdd.foreach((VoidFunction<WordCountRow>)wordCount->{
                try(Session session=cc.openSession()){
                    String query=String.format(Joiner.on(" ").join(
                            "INSERT INTO test_keyspace.word_count",
                            "(word, ts, count)",
                            "VALUES ('%s', %s, %s);"),
                            wordCount.word,wordCount.timestamp,wordCount.count);

                    session.execute(query);
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks